# Nested Form for Devise Account Types

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, nested-forms

I have Devise set up to create *Accounts*, which are linked to *Businesses* and *Personnel*. I'm trying to find a way to include the personnel info and the business info when you sign up for a new account. Is there a way to expand the new registration form? I also want it to change depending on which radio button is active (Personnel by default). I think a nested form is the way to go, but honestly I have no idea how to go about it.

The Business model and the Personnel model both have this line...

**app/models/Business.rb & app/models/Personnel.rb**

```
has_one :account, as :accountable
```

and the Account model looks like this...

**app/models/Account.rb**

```
class Account < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  belongs_to :accountable, polymorphic: true

  ACCOUNT_TYPES=["SuperAccount","Chamber","Personnel", "Business"]
  attr_accessor :type
end
```

Here's how I set up the registrations controller in case it helps.

**app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb**

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def new
    super
  end

  def create
    build_resource(sign_up_params)
    if (resource.type=="Personnel")
      resource.accountable = Personnel.new
      SignupNotifierMailer.personnel(@account).deliver
    elsif(resource.type =="Business")
      resource.accountable = Business.new
      SignupNotifierMailer.business(@account).deliver
    end
    resource.save
    yield resource if block_given?
    if resource.persisted?
      if resource.active_for_authentication?
        set_flash_message! :notice, :signed_up
        sign_up(resource_name, resource)
        respond_with resource, location: after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      else
        set_flash_message! :notice, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}"
        expire_data_after_sign_in!
        respond_with resource, location: after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      end
    else
      clean_up_passwords resource
      set_minimum_password_length
      respond_with resource
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @account.accountable.destroy!
    super
  end

  protected

    def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      if (resource.type == 'Personnel')
        edit_personnel_path(current_account.accountable_id)
      elsif (resource.type == 'Business')
        edit_business_path(current_account.accountable_id)
      else
        super
      end
    end
end
```

And finally, here's the view that I want to change.

**app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb**

```
<h2>Sign Up</h2>

<%= simple_nested_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :email, required: true, autofocus: true %>
    <%= f.input :password, required: true, hint: ("#{@minimum_password_length} 
        characters minimum" if @minimum_password_length) %>
    <%= f.input :password_confirmation, required: true %>
    <%= f.input :type, required: true, as: :radio_buttons, label: "Type of Account", 
            collection: Account::ACCOUNT_TYPES.drop(2), checked: 'Personnel' %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit, "Sign Up" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `accepts_nested_attributes_for :accountable` in your Account model, then you should be able to pass those on through to devise in the call to `build_resource`.

In your HTML form, you should use a nested form, which will generate form field names like `account[accountable][name]=Foobar` and that will be passed through to your model. You may need to include an `accountable_type` key and ensure it is within an acceptable range of options in the controller.

There is some information on the Devise readme that describes how to filter these parameters in the controller using strong parameters.

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#strong-parameters